# How to provide a tab-like button for creating new tabs in TabControl container

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol

In my form I have a TabControl container. Is there a way to place a button that looks like a tab itself on the right side of the already existing tabs? Furthermore the behaviour of the button has to be dynamic (move to the right as new tabs get added, move to the left as existing tabs are deleted).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define class variable

TabPage addTab=new TabPage("+");

then (in the from constructor after initialization, or in form load event) add this tab page to you  tabcontroll

```
tabControll.TabPages.Add(addTab);
```

then in SelectedIndexChanged event of your tabccontroll

```
if (tabControll.SelectedTab==addTab){
     var index=tabControll.TabPages.Count-1;
     var myNewTab=new TabPage("title");
     //what ever you want to do with the tab
     tabControll.TabPages.Insert(index,myNewTab);
     tabControll.SelectedTab=myNewTab;
}
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_